# How to use the file I/O write() instead of memcpy() to write the message to the SHM object

Tags: c, linux

```
int main() {

int mfd; //file descriptor for the shared object
int seg_size = (sizeof(message));   //shared object sized to store message 
char *shared_msg; 

// create the shared memory object with shm_open()  
mfd = shm_open(SHARED_OBJ_PATH, O_CREAT | O_RDWR, S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG);
if (mfd < 0) {
    perror("error in shm_open()");
    exit(1);
}

printf("I have created a lucky shared memory object:  %s\n",    SHARED_OBJ_PATH);

ftruncate(mfd, seg_size) ; // define size of shared memory object

// map the shared memory object to this process    
shared_msg = mmap(NULL, seg_size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, mfd, 0);
if (shared_msg == NULL) {
    perror("error in mmap()");
    exit(1);
}

printf("Shared memory is now allocated %d bytes\n", seg_size);

memcpy(shared_msg, "Hello Man", 30); //put something onto the   memory

printf("Message content is: %s\n\n Hit any key to finish!\n", shared_msg) ;
getchar() ; // wait for user to hit any key

shm_unlink(SHARED_OBJ_PATH) ;  // unlink - better to add error check

return 0 ;
}
```

I don't know how to use write function, I just delete memcpy() and change it to write (fd,  buf, 30), I do not know how to display "Hello Man".

Comment: What is `message`?

Comment: You cann't use `write(fd, ... )` to write to a buffer. `fd` should be a file descriptor instead of memory address. If you want formatted output, use [sprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/)

Comment: sprintf(shared_msg, "Hello man\n");

Comment: Even if it works on a given implementation (Linux), `write` is not a valid operation on a fd referring to a shared memory object.

Comment: But it asks me to use write() to complete this problem